# C# invoking a web service but IP being blocked after some amount of time

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, networking

I m invoking a web service and they stop my service calls after an hour,

```
the hourly limit of 5000 requests for the IP address MY IP :) 
has been exceeded.
```

I m using C#, and is there a way around this?

Can i programatically send the requests as if they are coming from different IP ?

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to send requests as if they come from a different IP (spoofing), but a response would be sent to the spoofed address and so it wouldn't do you much good.  The technique is one only used by crackers when they don't care about the response or the spoofed address is in some way the target.

What you need to do is adjust your code so that you aren't sending so many requests.  You can control when you send a request to the service.

Comment: Thanks, eh you are right. if i wait an hour for 5k request each hour, i need 40 hours, that s why i was thinking if there s a way around this.

Answer (score 1):

You could put all of your requests in a queue and and have a process that sends messages from this queue. If that process gets the error message back it can wait until it is allowed to send more messages. That way you can throw as many messages on the queue as you want without worrying about the 50k limit of the webservice you are hitting. You could look into [Queuing in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789048.aspx) as an example.